# Is it possible to use Spring SpEL expression in c:set to instantiate new class?

Tags: spring, jstl, spring-el

I would like to do something like:

```
<c:set var="customer" value="${new com.test.Customer()}" />
```

but this doesn't work.
Is there something like this possible?

Comment: JSTL knows nothing of Spring. You can create your own function using normal JSTL, though. But why would you want to create an instance of something in the view layer?

Comment: I'm using it to template a new empty row. But sure it can also be added to model in controller.

Comment: I'm just wondering if it's possible to use SpEL expression in value of <c:set>.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new spring:eval JSP tag that allows you to evaluate SpEL expressions from JSP pages, instead of c:set.